# Ruby hash lookup with multiple keys

Tags: ruby, hashtable

I have two array of hashes - `car_model` & `car_cc` as below. For each hash in `car_model` I need to lookup for the `cc` key and add that to `car_model`.

```
car_model = [
    {state: "MH", regno: 5555, model: "alto"},
    {state: "MH", regno: 5566, model: "alto"},
    {state: "DL", regno: 5555, model: "prius"},
    {state: "DL", regno: 5567, model: "nano"}
]

car_cc = [
    {state: "MH", regno: 5555, cc: 999},
    {state: "MH", regno: 5588, cc: 1800},
    {state: "DL", regno: 5555, cc: 1119},
    {state: "DL", regno: 5567, cc: nil}
]
```

Right now I use a regular `.each` loop to lookup for the `cc` key in `car_cc` and add that to each item in `car_model`.

```
car_model.each do |cm|
    car_cc.each do |cc|
        if(cm["state"]==cc["state"] && cm["regno"]==cc["regno"])
            cm["cc"] = cc["cc"]
            break
        end
    end
end
```

expected output

```
puts car_model
{:state=>"MH", :regno=>5555, :model=>"alto", :cc=>999}
{:state=>"MH", :regno=>5566, :model=>"alto", :cc=>nil}
{:state=>"DL", :regno=>5555, :model=>"prius", :cc=>1119}
{:state=>"DL", :regno=>5567, :model=>"nano", :cc=>nil}
=> nil
irb(main):008:0>
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this - faster and a more rubyistic way ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be to convert `car_cc` to a Hash with convenient keys:

```
cc = car_cc.each_with_object({}) { |car, h| h[car.values_at(:state, :regno)] = car[:cc] }
```

so that you can perform the join easier:

```
car_model.each { |h| h[:cc] = cc[h.values_at(:state, :regno)] }
```

This assumes that the `:state`/`:regno` pairs are unique in `car_cc` and that you want to modify `car_model`. If you don't want to modify `car_model` then you could say:

```
car_model_cc = car_model.map { |cm| cm.merge(cc: cc[cm.values_at(:state, :regno)]) }
```

to copy everything while adding the `:cc`s.

---

Of course with data sets this small any performance differences will be too small to worry about and if your data sets are much larger then you'd probably want to stuff it all in a database and let the database do the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 2):

```
car_model.map do |cm|
  cm.merge(car_cc.detect do |e|
             e[:state] == cm[:state] && e[:regno] == cm[:regno]
           end || {cc: nil})
end
```

or, DRY:

```
VALS = %i|state regno|
car_model.map do |cm|
  cm.merge(car_cc.detect do |e|
             [e, cm].map { |e| e.values_at(*VALS) }.reduce(:==)
           end || {cc: nil})
end
```

If the amount of items to lookup is big enough, I would start with building an intermediate object:

```
map = car_cc.group_by { |e| e.values_at(:state, :regno) }
            .map { |k, v| [k, v.first[:cc]] }.to_h
#⇒ {
#    [ "MH", 5555 ] => 999,
#    [ "MH", 5588 ] => 1800,
#    [ "DL", 5555 ] => 1119,
#    [ "DL", 5567 ] => nil
# }
```

Now everything is smooth:

```
car_model.each do |cm|
  cm[:cc] = map[[cm[:state], cm[:regno]]]
end
```

Comment: Good idea to use `detect`.

Answer (score 1):

```
model = car_model.each_with_object({}) { |g,h|
  h[g.values_at(:state, :regno)] = g.merge(:cc => nil) }
  #=> {["MH", 5555]=>{:state=>"MH", :regno=>5555, :model=>"alto", :cc=>nil},
  #    ["MH", 5566]=>{:state=>"MH", :regno=>5566, :model=>"alto", :cc=>nil},
  #    ["DL", 5555]=>{:state=>"DL", :regno=>5555, :model=>"prius", :cc=>nil},
  #    ["DL", 5567]=>{:state=>"DL", :regno=>5567, :model=>"nano", :cc=>nil}} 

cc = car_cc.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h[g.values_at(:state, :regno)] = g }.
  select { |k,_| model.key?(k) }
  #=> {["MH", 5555]=>{:state=>"MH", :regno=>5555, :cc=>999},
  #    ["DL", 5555]=>{:state=>"DL", :regno=>5555, :cc=>1119},
  #    ["DL", 5567]=>{:state=>"DL", :regno=>5567, :cc=>nil}} 

(model.merge(cc) { |_,o,n| o.merge(n) }).values 
  #=> [{:state=>"MH", :regno=>5555, :model=>"alto", :cc=>999},
  #    {:state=>"MH", :regno=>5566, :model=>"alto", :cc=>nil},
  #    {:state=>"DL", :regno=>5555, :model=>"prius", :cc=>1119},
  #    {:state=>"DL", :regno=>5567, :model=>"nano", :cc=>nil}]
```

**Notes**

In the calculation of `cc` we first calculate the following hash before removing keys-value pairs `k,v` for which `model` does not contain a key `k`.

```
car_cc.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h[g.values_at(:state, :regno)] = g }
  #=> {["MH", 5555]=>{:state=>"MH", :regno=>5555, :cc=>999},
  #    ["MH", 5588]=>{:state=>"MH", :regno=>5588, :cc=>1800},
  #    ["DL", 5555]=>{:state=>"DL", :regno=>5555, :cc=>1119},
  #    ["DL", 5567]=>{:state=>"DL", :regno=>5567, :cc=>nil}}
```

In the last line of code we compute the following hash before extracting its values.

```
model.merge(cc) { |_,o,n| o.merge(n) }
  #=> {["MH", 5555]=>{:state=>"MH", :regno=>5555, :model=>"alto", :cc=>999},
  #    ["MH", 5566]=>{:state=>"MH", :regno=>5566, :model=>"alto", :cc=>nil},
  #    ["DL", 5555]=>{:state=>"DL", :regno=>5555, :model=>"prius", :cc=>1119},
  #    ["DL", 5567]=>{:state=>"DL", :regno=>5567, :model=>"nano", :cc=>nil}}
```

This last calculation uses the form of [Hash#merge](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) that employs a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged. See the doc for an explanation of the three block variables (here `_`, `o` and `n`, the first being an underscore merely to signify that that variable is not used in the block calculation).

Comment: After looking at the other answers I've concluded that my answer is inferior to those given by @muistooshort and...

Comment: ... @mudasobwa. I could have skipped the `select` operation if, instead of merging `cc` into `model`, I used `find/detect` for each key of `model` to find the key-value pair of `cc` to merge into `model`, as Mudsie did, or simply added the applicable key key-value pair for key `:cc` from `cc`, as  did.